# Read Data From Text File And Sum Numbers

Tags: java, input, io, text-files

I want to read in data from a text file which is full of integers and have the program print those integers out to the screen while summing them.  This shouldn't be hard, but I can't figure it out!!!

Here is the extremely simplified text file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

And here is my code that is supposed to work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("Some_Numbers.txt"));

        filereader(textfile);
    }   


    static void filereader(Scanner textfile)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while(i <= 19)
        {
            System.out.println(textfile.nextInt());
            sum = sum + textfile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    }



}
```

Finally, here is the output I get:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at ReadFile.filereader(ReadFile.java:23)
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:12)
```

Comment: You should use `nextLong()` instead of `nextInt()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling textfile.nextInt() twice in the loop. Try:

```
static void filereader(Scanner textfile)     
{         
    int i = 0;         
    int sum = 0;          
    while(i <= 19)         
    {       
        int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();          

        System.out.println(nextInt);             
        sum = sum + nextInt;
        i++;         
    }     
}
```

Comment: That.....is genius.  I would not have thought of that.  It's so easy to do in FORTRAN lol.  In FORTRAN you just have to do something like:

`integer::i, sum, variablename

i = 0
sum = 0

OPEN(UNIT=99, file=('Some_Numbers.txt'), form='formatted)
DO i = 1,19
    READ(99, '(I2)') variablename 
    PRINT*, variablename
    sum = sum + variablename
ENDDO
CLOSE(99)
PRINT*, sum`

Much more intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: You're welcome, perhaps you will consider marking my answer as accepted if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

You never increment `i`, so the while loop continues beyond the end of the file. As for summing, do something like this.

```
static void addstuff(Scanner aScanner) {
        int sum = 0;

        while (aScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += aScanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
}
```

This will run until [hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) returns false, which occurs when the next item the scanner sees isn't an integer. This could be non-numeric input or the end of the file. This means you're no longer limited to 25 integers - it'll read as many as it can before stopping.

Answer (score 4):

Because you never increment `i`, it never changes from 0, so it is always less than 25. That means it tries to look again after it has done 25 elements, but there is no 26th, so there's an exception.

Instead of a `while` loop, I would recommend a `for` loop.

To sum them, instead of printing them out, just add to an accumulator.

```
int accumulator = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    accumulator += aScanner.nextInt();

System.out.println(accumulator);
```

should print out the sum.

Comment: its `nextInt()` in Java, you might be thinking of C# ;)

Comment: @peterlawrey Thanks. I wasn't thinking of C#, I just wasn't thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to lockstock's answer, you might want to consider adding textfile.hasNext() OR textfile.hasNextInt() for your while loop.

```
static void filereader(Scanner textfile) {
int sum = 0;          
while(textfile.hasNextInt()) {
    int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(nextInt);
    sum += nextInt;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do following thing

```
    while(i < 25)
    {
        System.out.println(aScanner.nextInt());
        i++ ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It throws an exception because you don't increment `i` in the loop. In case if the number of integers in the input file is unknown, you can use the [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method to check the presence of the next integer (or just use `hasNext()` to check for EOF).

You can sum the numbers like in the code snippet below:

```
    ...
    int sum = 0;
    while(i++ < 25)
    {
        sum += aScanner.nextInt();
    }
```

or

```
    ...
    int sum = 0;
    while(aScanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        sum += aScanner.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: The link is broken for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error (exception) because your file has very big numbers that do not fit on **Integer** types. You should use **Long**.

So, use: `aScanner.nextLong()` instead of `aScanner.nextInt()`.

**EDIT:** You should also change the type of the `sum` variable from `int` to `long`.

Your code will work fine.

Comment: I changed my code to: `sum = sum + aScanner.NextLong();` but I still get the same error.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know if it works. Try to change the type of `sum` from `int` to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Your `i` is **never Incremented.**

**2.** You are **not** adding up numbers.

**3.** `addstuff(diskScanner)` is a `static memeber`, so call it with **class name with dot operator.**

**Eg:**

```
Add.addstuff(diskScanner);

   static void addstuff(Scanner aScanner)
{
    int i = 0;
    long l = 0;


    while(i < 25)
    {
        l = i + l;
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(l);



}
```