# Creating a FileReader which way is better for optimisation?

Tags: java, file, file-io, filereader, java-io

From an optimization stand point is it better to declare the File separately like this

```
File f = new File("sample.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
```

Or is it better to do it inline like this

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("sample.txt));]
```

Aren't really sure if it even matters really.

Comment: It's better not to use a `FileReader` at all, since it doesn't allow you to specify file encoding. Use an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I'm not sure the encoding and locale is matters here.

Comment: @Roman - Encoding always matters if you're reading/writing character data from a byte stream. **Always**. If it didn't there wouldn't be > 20,000 hits *from this site alone* for the Google query "invalid byte utf-8".

Comment: Using `FileReader` is a bug. Period. And it doesn't matter how fast the code runs if it's buggy. You just get get the wrong results sooner.

Comment: @kdgregory This's not a question about what character encoding in *sample.txt*.

Comment: @Roman - :sigh: I am well aware that the OP did not ask about encoding. In fact, I suspect the OP has no clue that encoding is important. I'm trying to make him aware that it is, so that he doesn't add to the pile of buggy code that doesn't get encoding right. In my opinion, that's far more important than discussing a pointless micro-optimization (which others have already done).

Comment: There's [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875446/read-data-from-text-file-and-sum-numbers/11870863#11870863) and [other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208999/how-can-i-retrieve-information-from-text-file-using-java-streams/13209144#13209144) of my answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no difference. Do whatever's more readable in your particular situation.

It's *possible* that it could affect when the `File` object is eligible for garbage collection, but I'd be *hugely* surprised to see a situation in which that's a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to reference the just-created instance `new File("sample.txt)` later in your code, then `File f = new File("sample.txt");` would be required. You would be able to access it via the reference variable `f`.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Whether you create a `Object Reference Variable` of type `File` to have a reference to the `File` object or not, it will still be present on the `heap`.

**-** Yes its quite valid that having a `Object Reference Variable` will help you refer back to that `File` object when you need it the next time....

Answer (score 1):

*The difference is obviously the file object couldn't be easily accessed in the code in inline version. And it makes the code less readable, maintainable, and debuggable.*