# I cant get sum of numbers in txt file with fileinputstream in Java

Tags: java, fileinputstream

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class HW104 {
    static int z;
    static int k;
    public static void inputData(String filename) {
        
        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
            int i = input.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                
                System.out.println((char) i);
                i = input.read();
                z=z+i;
                
                
                
            }
            System.out.println(z);
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputData("arabaa.txt");
    }
}
```

I cant get sum of numbers in txt file with fileinputstream in Java. int z must be sum of all numbers in txt file. But i got irrelevant number.

Comment: Look carefully at the logic.  You are discarding (i.e. not including in the sum) the first value that you read.

Comment: How can i fix this. I wrote in file 1,2,3,4..,10 but i got 781 as a result

Comment: A second problem is that you are reading and summing characters.  Not numbers.  Read the javadoc for `Scanner`.

Comment: Check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875446/read-data-from-text-file-and-sum-numbers

Comment: `z += (i - '0');` is what you need if summing digits